# Google Sheets: How can I Flatten and Split Data while including multiple columns?

Tags: google-sheets, split, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, flatten

I would like to pull data from Google Sheets form responses that include checkboxes. The checkboxes are output into single column cells by commas.

Data/Form Responses sheet:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O99Gz.png)

Current and Expected Results
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5FtM.png)

Current Formula

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(IFERROR(SPLIT('Form Responses'!E2:E, ","))="",,
 'Form Responses'!B2:B&"×"&SPLIT('Form Responses'!E2:E, ","))), "×"), 
 "where Col2 is not null")))
```

If anyone could please help I would appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## SUGGESTION

Perhaps you can try this tweaked formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(IFERROR(SPLIT('Form Responses'!E2:E, ","))="",,TEXT('Form Responses'!A2:A,"MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS")&"×"&'Form Responses'!B2:B&"×"&'Form Responses'!C2:C&"×"&'Form Responses'!D2:D&"×"&SPLIT('Form Responses'!E2:E, ","))),"×"),"where Col2 is not null")))
```

### Demo

[image]

---

Answer (score 0):

You may try this `LAMBDA()` formula. You just need to adjust ranges in lambda input parameter.

```
=LAMBDA(UnpivotCol,AdjucentCols,QUERY(REDUCE(,REDUCE(,UnpivotCol,LAMBDA(a,x,VSTACK(a,TOCOL(INDEX(JOIN("|",INDEX(AdjucentCols,ROW(x)-(INDEX(ROW(UnpivotCol),1)-1))) & "|" & SPLIT(x,",")))))),LAMBDA(t,g,VSTACK(t,SPLIT(g,"|")))),"offset 2 format Col1 'm/d/yyyy'",0))(E2:E4,A2:D4)
```

[image]