# Google Sheet or Excel Text to rows

Tags: excel, google-sheets, libreoffice-calc

I've trouble converting text in the spreadsheet into rows. All Google examples are using the options text to columns and then transpose.
The initial table structure.

| company | email |
| --- | --- |
| Company 1 | john@company1.com, mary@company1.com,info@company1.com |
| Company 2 | john@company2.com, mary@company2.com,info@company2.com |

I want it to convert into and after filling the company field down.

| company | email |
| --- | --- |
| Company 1 | john@company1.com |
|  | mary@company1.com |
|  | info@company1.com |
| Company 2 | john@company2.com |
|  | mary@company2.com |
|  | info@company2.com |

Comment: Use Text to Columns, then transpose.

Comment: I don't think it can be achieved with normal formulas because after text to columns you want emails into rows. Probably a script/macro could achieve it

Comment: Please edit your question show what you have tried? You list three different spreadsheet programs. Which one are you really using?  It can certainly be done in recent versions of Excel & Power Query. I'm not as familiar with Sheets and have no experience with Libre Office.

Comment: the very tag definition of `excel` states: `Do NOT use with other spreadsheet software like [google-sheets]` and the `Google-Sheets` tag definition: `Do NOT use with [excel].`  Mixing tags usually gets the question closed as too broad.`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Sheets: How can I Flatten and Split Data while including multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75465907/google-sheets-how-can-i-flatten-and-split-data-while-including-multiple-columns) It has a similar concept to your issue if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Do some example scripts exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In LibreOffice Calc, for such tasks I use this trick:

I write down for the first cell the formula of the form `=A1&CHAR(9)&SUBSTITUTE(B1;",";CHAR(10)&A1&CHAR(9))`
and copy the formula to the end of the list.

Then select a column and use [**Data - Text to Columns**](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/shared/00/00000208.html) with separator **Tab**.

[image: Demo]

Comment: Thanks! This solution works. Would it be possible for you to take some time and explain how this formula works?